# Merge multiple branches into one

Tags: git, git-extensions

Can I use git extensions app to merge multiple branches into one. Let's say I have multiple branches, each for a c++ class. I make some modifications to some classes, which means commiting to different branches. Now a merging will be easy since no conflicts are possible. How can I reduce the painful job of doing manually all the multiple branches merging with only one command using git extensions (or other way)?

Answer (score 1):

plain old `git merge`, just list all your branch names.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using Git Extensions. Switch to the branch you want to add the other branches to and then bring up the "Merge branches" dialog by using the keyboard shortcut "Ctrl+M".

Next to the dropdown where you can select a branch to fetch changes from there is a button. Clicking this button will bring up a new window where you can select multiple branches to bring in changes from. The result of this will be that the names of all the selected branches now appear in the dropdown textarea.

There you go. =)

Comment: @Arenhg: is there a way to do a "all branches merge in the same point"? That is whithout selecting every branch and than merge the upper branch into them, get all of them to the same, highest point in development.

Comment: @CPJ: Not quite sure what you mean, but I'll try anyway. If you select multiple branches git will use the appropriate merge strategy and all branches will be merged into one new revision in the destination branch.

Comment: If you have 3 branches and do they way you described, You will join all branches into current one, so the current one has all updates from all other branches. All other branches will be in the same spot as they were before multi-merge. That means that You can't continue development on any other branch (except multi-merged-into branch) and use the updates from all branches. Hope this clarifies what I'm trying to say. Tx.

Comment: _"If you have 3 branches and do they way you described, You will join all branches into current one, so the current one has all updates from all other branches. All other branches will be in the same spot as they were before multi-merge"_ <-- **correct**.

_"That means that You can't continue development on any other branch and use the updates from all branches"_ <-- **correct**.

In the end you will have to add the changes you want/need to the branches you want/need to work in - repeatedly. There's really no other way around it. =)